# How nginx lost installed module?

Tags: nginx

Some days ago i had installed nginx with rtmp module.
When i did `nginx -V` i got:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: <alot of text> --add-module=/home/administrator/nginx/nginx-rtmp-module-master
```

And after i add rtmp block in `nginx.conf` i got no errors.

Today i tried to continue my work. Restart serveice and got en error:

```
unknown derective "rtmp" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:6
```

I check modules `nginx -V` and not found rtmp module i mean this string:

```
--add-module=/home/administrator/nginx/nginx-rtmp-module-master
```

Whats heppens? How module can dissapiered?

Comment: maybe an update via your package manager replaced it with an nginx that doesn't know rtmp?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek I did not do any commands.

Comment: Somebody else on your system? Or do you have "unattended-upgrades" or such a thing installed? Or maybe you have different nginx installed in different PATHs and after logging in (maybe as a different user) the system found a different nginx executable?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek only i have access. And this situation confused my couse i completly new with Linux.\

Comment: you can check whether you have multile nginx installed: `find / -name nginx`

Comment: @TomášPospíšek i found a lot of `nginx` string how can i check that this just folder name or nginx instance?

Comment: `stat INSERT_THE_PATH_OF_THE_FILES_THAT_WERE_FOUND`
The output will tell you on the top right what kind of file that is. The "Access" line tell you whether the file is "x"ecutable